# Как избежать двойного цикла и оптимизировать?

Tags: javascript

```
const find = (arr, parametres) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < parametres.length; i++) {
        let founded = false;
        for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (
                arr[j].property1 === parametres[i].property1 &&
                arr[j].property2 === parametres[i].property2
            ) {
                founded = true;
            }
        }
        if (parametres[i].type === 'type1') {
            if (founded) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (parametres[i].type === 'type2') {
            if (!founded) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

Comment: что такое `action` и `subject`

Comment: свойств объекта. строки

Comment: например action = 'action1', subject='subject2'

Comment: Что должен делать код?